# Unknown, Un-encryted Connections

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, encryption, connections, ssl

We have SSL enabled on our SQL servers and our monitoring tool is alerting that there are unencrypted connections.

The check that monitors this runs every minute and uses the following query to check:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    sys.dm_exec_connections
WHERE   encrypt_option <> 'TRUE'
```

I did some further investigation, setting up an agent job to dump the results of the following query into a table (the job runs every minute)

```
SELECT  c.*,
        r.status,
        r.command,
        r.last_wait_type,
        s.host_name,
        s.program_name,
        s.client_interface_name,
        s.login_name,
        s.database_id,
        qs.text
FROM    sys.dm_exec_connections c
        LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests r
            ON c.connection_id = r.connection_id
        LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s
            ON c.session_id = s.session_id
        OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) qs
WHERE   encrypt_option <> 'TRUE'
```

If I select from my table, I see some results (spread across three screenshots due to wide result set):

[image]

[image]

[image]

To me, `sys.dm_exec_connections` doesn't give a lot to go on here. The only thing that seems particular to these connections is they are all endpoint 2 (`TSQL Local Machine`) and have an auth_schema of `(unknown)`

I can exclude these from monitoring on that basis but I'd like to be sure they are benign before doing so.

What are these connections? Why are they un-encrypted when SSL is enabled? Is there any further information I could look at to understand them better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sys.dm_exec_connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql) DMV returns all currently established connections whereas [sys.dm_exec_sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql) returns one row per authenticated session. The implication is a row in `sys.dm_exec_connections` may exist without a corresponding row in `sys.dm_exec_sessions` until a newly established connection completes the initial handshake and authentication process. This is typically a short-lived condition on a healthy instance.

Consider changing the `sys.dm_exec_sessions` join to an `INNER JOIN` so that only authenticated sessions are returned. These should show `encrypt_option = 'TRUE'` because the TLS handshake will be complete after authentication.

Comment: I wonder what this shows using the new TDS v8, where the TLS handshake happens before the TDS handshake.

Comment: @Charlieface, I am curious about same. My guess is the connection will show encrypted when the TCP connection is established but I don't have a test environment to verify.

Comment: Handshakes go TCP -> TLS -> TDS in that case, so might not be true.

Comment: @Charlieface, then if a query of `sys.dm_exec_connections` returns a TCP connection before the TLS handshake, it probably won't show encrypted at that point.